# R, conditional summing of every second cell in each row

Tags: r, sum

I have a data frame and want for each row the sum of every second cell (beginning with the second cell), whose left neighbor is greater than zero. Here's an example:

```
a <- c(-2,1,1,-2)
b <- c(1,2,3,4)
c <- c(-2,1,-1,2)
d <- c(5,6,7,8)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

This gives:

```
> df
   a b  c d
1 -2 1 -2 5
2  1 2  1 6
3  1 3 -1 7
4 -2 4  2 8
```

For the first row the correct sum is 0 (the left neighbor of 1 is -2 and the left neighbor of 5 is also -2); for the second it's 8; for the third it's 3; for the fourth it's again 8.

I want to do it without loops, so I tried it with `sum()` and `which()` like in [Conditional Sum in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827705/conditional-sum-in-r), but could not find a way through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We subset the dataset for alternating columns using the recycling vector (`c(TRUE, FALSE)`) to get the 1st, 3rd, ...etc columns of the dataset, convert it to a logical vector by checking whether it is greater than 0 ( `> 0`), then multiply the values with the second subset of alternating columns ie. columns 2nd, 4th etc. by using the recycling vector (`c(FALSE, TRUE)`).  The idea is that if there are values in the left column that are less than 0, it will be FALSE in the logical matrix and it gets coerced to 0 by multiplying with the other subset.  Finally, do the `rowSums` to get the expected output

```
rowSums((df[c(TRUE, FALSE)]>0)*df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
#[1] 0 8 3 8
```

It can be also replaced with `seq`

```
rowSums((df[seq(1, ncol(df), by = 2)]>0)*df[seq(2, ncol(df), by = 2)])
#[1] 0 8 3 8
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `Map`

```
Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, lapply(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], `>`, 0), df[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
#[1] 0 8 3 8
```

Comment: This works fine, but I don't get how. What's the `*` operator doing?

Comment: @Joe It is the operator for multiplication so as the convert the corresponding values to 0 for FALSE in other logical matrix