# How to sum a column in R filtered by the value of another column? Or to a specific row?

Tags: r

I want to find the column sum for a data set when another column is a specific value. Below is a screen grab of my data, I want to sum the farmID for each iteration.

My guess would be that the code is IF(iteration=x), sum(FarmID) but I don't know how to make that happen.

partial screenshot of data

[image: partial screenshot of data]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Also show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It will be something like : ````sum( df$farmid [ df$iteration==x] )```` .

Comment: aha! It's: ```sum(df$`Farm ID`[which(df$Iteration==x)])``` Finally found it in this post: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827705/conditional-sum-in-r>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use `library(dplyr)` functions.
For example you can sum the farm IDs by iteration as such:

```
yourdata %>% 
  group_by(Iteration) %>% 
  summarise(Farm_ID_sum = sum(Farm ID))
```

An example:

```
example <- data.frame(
   "Iteration" = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE), 
   "FarmID" = sample(1:500, 20, replace = TRUE)
   )

example %>% 
   group_by(Iteration) %>% 
   summarise(Farm_ID_sum = sum(FarmID))

# Gives the output:
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Iteration Farm_ID_sum
      <int>       <int>
1         1         790
2         2         694
3         3         391
4         4        1588
5         5        1828
```

Comment: This was great! Thank you. I was just starting to search for a way to do it all in one line versus each iteration individually.