# How do I get the sum of a column where observations from another column is "yes"

Tags: r, sum

I am trying to find out the total Project_Amount in my data for projects where the Disadvantaged Community (DAC) column states "Yes."

This dataset has a total of 2,738 observations. 827 of which have "Yes" in the DAC column.

There are no NA in the Project_Amount column. Instead they are inputted as 0.00.
The only inputs in the DAC columns are "Yes" and "NA"

```
> head(DAC_indicators)
# A tibble: 6 × 12
  Recipient_Contractor    Project_Title Project_Amount Project_City  DAC
  <chr>                   <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>
1 ABAG                    Bay Area EV …         14533. San Francis…   Yes
2 CA EV Alliance          Bay Area Cha…         12474. Fremont        Yes
3 RTC Fuels, LLC dba Pea… Pearson Fuel…         71053  La Mesa        NA
4 Blink Acquisition       Nissan Elect…          6849. El Cajon       Yes
5 Redwood Coast Energy A… North Coast …         70000  Orleans        NA
6 ABAG                    Bay Area EV …          7266. Hollister      NA
# ℹ 8 more variables: Project_Zip <chr>, County <chr>,
#   Disadvantaged_Community_OEHHA <chr>,
#   Disadvantaged_Community_SB535 <chr>,
#   `DAC(CARB)_LIC(CARB)` <chr>,
#   Disadvantaged_Community_CES3 <chr>,
#   Disadvantaged_Community_CES4 <chr>, DAC <chr>
```

I tried this based on what I found online and it really seemed like it should work but I kept getting "NA" returns.
I tried different variations of this. Here are two -

```
> with(DAC_indicators, sum(Project_Amount[DAC == 'Yes']))
[1] NA
> with(DAC_indicators, sum(DAC_indicators$Project_Amount[DAC_indicators$DAC == "Yes"]))
[1] NA
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Sum in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827705/conditional-sum-in-r)

Comment: You need na.rm = TRUE in your `sum()` .

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

DAC_indicators %>%
  filter(DAC == "Yes") %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Project_Amount, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Here we filter the data to include only cases where DAC is "Yes" and then sum the Project_Amount column, while removing NA cases (just in case they are somewhere in this column).

So using the first six rows of your given data as `DAC_indicators`:

```
DAC_indicators <- data.frame(
  Recipient_Contractor = c("ABAG", "CA EV Alliance", "RTC Fuels, LLC dba Pea…", "Blink Acquisition", "Redwood Coast Energy A…", "ABAG"),
  Project_Title = c("Bay Area EV …", "Bay Area Cha…", "Pearson Fuel…", "Nissan Elect…", "North Coast …", "Bay Area EV …"),
  Project_Amount = c(14533, 12474, 71053, 6849, 70000, 7266),
  Project_City = c("San Francis…", "Fremont", "La Mesa", "El Cajon", "Orleans", "Hollister"),
  DAC = c("Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", NA, NA)
)
```

We get output:

```
A data.frame: 1 × 1
total
<dbl>
33856
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```
DAC_indicators <- data.frame(
  Recipient_Contractor = c("ABAG", "CA EV Alliance", "RTC Fuels, LLC dba Pea…", "Blink Acquisition", "Redwood Coast Energy A…", "ABAG"),
  Project_Title = c("Bay Area EV …", "Bay Area Cha…", "Pearson Fuel…", "Nissan Elect…", "North Coast …", "Bay Area EV …"),
  Project_Amount = c(14533, 12474, 71053, 6849, 70000, 7266),
  Project_City = c("San Francis…", "Fremont", "La Mesa", "El Cajon", "Orleans", "Hollister"),
  DAC = c("Yes", "Yes", NA, "Yes", NA, NA)
)

sum(DAC_indicators$Project_Amount[DAC_indicators$DAC == "Yes"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Like the tidyverse version, this selects the subset of cases and then does the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your base R version is that we need `FALSE` instead of `NA` in the filter values.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
x[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]
[1] 1 3 # fine
x[c(TRUE, NA, TRUE)]
[1]  1 NA  3  # we get an NA element that we can't sum
```

Below I've taken Jay Bee's snippet to create `DAC_indicators` and renamed it `df`:

```
df$DAC == "Yes" 
[1] TRUE TRUE   NA TRUE   NA   NA  # this won't work as a filter, by analogy with the above
    
df$DAC == "Yes" & !is.na(df$DAC)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  # but this will
          
sum(with(df, Project_Amount[DAC == "Yes" & !is.na(DAC)]))
[1] 33856
```

Comment: `%in%` would be better here than an additional `!is.na(…)` - `sum(with(df, Project_Amount[DAC %in% "Yes"]))`